# Mysql query - how to include "filter"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables, with both a large number of rows. The first table has an overview of products, the second has additional information for the products. The tables look as following:

```
    #Products
    + ---------- + ------ + ------------ +
    | Product_Id | Status | EAN          |
    + ---------- + ------ + ------------ +
    | 1          | 1      | 0123456789   |
    | 2          | 1      | 9876543210   |
    | 3          | 1      | 6548214656   |
    | 4          | 2      | 245511411241 |
    | 5          | 1      | 8888888888   |
    | etc.       | etc .  | etc.         |
    + ---------- + ------ + ------------ +
```

```
     #Info
        + ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
        | Info_Id | EAN          | Info_Type | Info_Value |
        + ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
        | 1       | 0123456789   | brand     | brand1     |
        | 2       | 0123456789   | type      | type1      |
        | 3       | 0123456789   | price     | 0.00       |
        | 4       | 9876543210   | brand     | brand6     |
        | 5       | 9876543210   | type      | type3      |
        | 6       | 9876543210   | price     | 15.00      |
        | 7       | 6548214656   | brand     | brand34    |
        | 8       | 6548214656   | type      | type1      |
        | 9       | 6548214656   | price     | 99.00      |
        | 10      | 245511411241 | brand     | brand324   |
        | 11      | 245511411241 | type      | type1      |
        | 12      | 245511411241 | price     | 98.00      |
        | 13      | 8888888888   | brand     | brand1     |
        | 14      | 8888888888   | price     | 9.00       |
        | 14      | 8888888888   | type      | type4      |
        | etc.    | etc.         | etc.      | etc.       |
        + ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
```

With the following query I am able to find the addtional information corresponding to the product by matching the EAN's:

```
     select    i.EAN
            , p.ProductStatus
            , max(case info_type when 'brand' then info_value end) as brand
            , max(case info_type when 'type' then info_value end) as [type]
            , max(case info_type when 'price' then info_value end) as price
        from #Info i
        inner join #Products p on p.ean = i.ean
        WHERE p.Status=1
        group by i.EAN, p.ProductStatus ORDER BY P.Product_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

This provides me the following table:

```
     + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
        | EAN          | Status | brand    | type  | price |     
        + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
        | 0123456789   | 1      | brand1   | type1 | 0.00  |
        | 6548214656   | 1      | brand34  | type1 | 99.00 |
        | 9876543210   | 1      | brand6   | type3 | 15.00 |
        | 8888888888   | 1      | brand1   | type4 | 9.00  |
        | etc. (10 products)                               |
        + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
```

However, now I want to be able to filter for specific brands, types or prices. For example, I only want to select products for which the price is larger than 50 (Info_Type=price AND Info_Value>50.00) and second the brand is a specific brand, lets say "brand1" (Info_Type=brand AND Info_Value=brand1). Could someone tell me how I could include this into my query? Tried many things, most close I came to the desired result is the following query:

```
    select    i.EAN
        , p.ProductStatus
        , max(case when (info_type = 'brand' AND info_value='brand1') then info_value end) as brand
        , max(case info_type when 'type' then info_value end) as [type]
        , max(case info_type when 'price' then info_value end) as price
    from #Info i
    inner join #Products p on p.ean = i.ean
    WHERE p.Status=1
    group by i.EAN, p.ProductStatus ORDER BY P.Product_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, this gives the following result:

```
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
    | EAN          | Status | brand    | type  | price |     
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
    | 0123456789   | 1      | brand1   | type1 | 0.00  |
    | 6548214656   | 1      | NULL     | type1 | 99.00 |
    | 9876543210   | 1      | NULL     | type3 | 15.00 |
    | 8888888888   | 1      | brand1   | type4 | 9.00  |
    | etc. (10 products)                               |
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
```

I would like to see the following result:

```
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
    | EAN          | Status | brand    | type  | price |     
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
    | 0123456789   | 1      | brand1   | type1 | 0.00  |
    | 8888888888   | 1      | brand1   | type4 | 9.00  |
    | etc. (10 products)                               |
    + ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
```

Who helps me out? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
select i.EAN, p.ProductStatus,
       max(case when (info_type = 'brand' AND info_value='brand1') then info_value end) as brand,
       max(case info_type when 'type' then info_value end) as [type],
       max(case info_type when 'price' then info_value end) + 0 as price
from #Info i inner join
     #Products p
     on p.ean = i.ean
where p.Status=1
group by i.EAN, p.ProductStatus
having price < 10
order by P.Product_id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The `+ 0` is because `info_value` seems to be stored as a string.  However, you want `Price` to be a number, so this converts it to a number.

Comment: @mh3982 . . . The query is based on the query in your question.  I was pointing out how to use `having` for the filtering.

Comment: Thnx. Where is the +0 for at the price selection? Anyway, this seems to be the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @mh3982 .  . . It is in the `SELECT` clause.